# Allow only one ipaddress through a cisco firewall without pcs knowing there is a proxy server

Tags: networking, proxy, firewall, cisco

We have a PC behind a firewall. (ASA 5505)

[PC] => [ASA Firewall] =>  [Corporate Proxy/Firewall/Anything] => [Internet]

:- where the PC and ASA Firewall are under our control... and the rest are owned and managed by our clients.

I need the PC to be able to only access a single ip-address on the internet. (on port 80 and https)

For various reasons I don't want the PC to know that outside the firewall internet goes through a proxy server.

I also don't want to force the corporation to have to change their proxy server settings.

Is it possible to get a cisco (ASA) firewall to translate a request to an ip-address into a proxy request, and block all other ip addresses?

Is there some other solution that involves only configuration of the firewall?

Comment: What model of Cisco is there?

Answer (score 0):

This is not my area but I think you are looking for the [Web Cache Coordination Protocol](https://supportforums.cisco.com/docs/DOC-32709) (WCCP) and/or possibly the [Transparent Firewall](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa82/configuration/guide/config/fwmode.html) functionality of the ASA.